# CollapsingToolbarLayout + Coordinatorlayout + ViewPager + Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have searched around but it seems that there is no similar issue like mine.

I have a ViewPager with several fragments. Inside each fragment, there is a header part that i want it to collapse (pallax) when the below part is scrolled (usually a RecylcerView). The Collapsing part is another Fragment (so i can reuse at several places).

The first fragment (in the ViewPager) that has this layout is working fine (picture A). However, the others will have an issue like the picture B. When you change the order of the fragments inside ViewPager, for example B to first, A to second, then A will get the issue, B will work fine.

A is working fine (A is the first fragment in ViewPager)
[Pic A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XNOl.png)

B has overlapping issue. There is a space at top, the bottom is overlapped by the list below
[Pic B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0dh8.png)

When scroll up the reclyclerview below, the top part does not completely collapse

Here is the layout, both A & B use the same layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_test"
                android:name="com.sample.android.fragment.FragmentTest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/test_height"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_emtpy"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

- layout_list just contains a RecyclerView

Ps: i have tried several ways: 
- android:fitsSystemWindows for AppBarLayout, CoordinatorLayout...
- Put the list into AppBarLayout

Answer (score 0):

I faced kinda same problem; bugs with coordinate layout.
Give this library a try , sample app is there too on playStore.

```
https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout
```

you will have to modify the viewPager and adapter also I guess;
However integration shouldn't take long .
First go through sample app on play store and figure out whether it will do you some good or not.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will give it a try although it seems none of the options is similar to my design (collapsing area inside fragment of a view pager & is a fragment itself)

Comment: FYI: The library does not help to solve the issue. Actually, it causes another flickering issue when the layout is scrolled up. I guess i have to use another strategy for this layout. Thanks for the suggestion though